# DataRow[] + расширение LINQ

Tags: c#

Есть массив строк `DataRow[] datarows`. Одна из колонок имеет имя *Sum*. Как получить максимальное значение по данной колонке при помощи расширения LINQ? Спасибо.

Comment: В datarow список пользователей и соответственно паролей. При добавлении нового пользователя мне нужно знать последний ИД.

Comment: хранится в одной из таблиц SQLite

Comment: Также ещё можете использовать `Dapper` для данной задачи (по сути это расширения для ADO.NET), потому что работа с чистым ADO.NET не так эффективна.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если оставить в стороне то, что вы работаете с массивом `DataRow`, а ответить на конкретно поставленный вопрос, то поиск максимального элемента не будет сильно отличатся от поиска элемента в массиве содержащим в себе объекты определенного класса.

Вы можете получить доступ к столбцам `DataRow` используя индексаторы (по названию столбца или индексу (отсчет от 0)), которые вернут объект типа `object`.

Также можно добавить ссылку на `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` и воспользоваться методами расширения `Field`, которые предоставляют строго типизированный доступ к вашим столбцам.

Таким образом ваш код будет примерно следующим:

```
        var max =
            datarows
            .Select(x => x.Field<int>("Sum"))
            .Max();
```